# Grappling to grapling point + offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple game in Unity in 2d. So I have the player and I have a grappler gun. And when I press the right mouse button and the mouse position is in the direction of any object it will grappler to this object. But my question is, I have a small circle (Grappling point) and it is very hard to put the mouse to the grappler point circle direction in the air. so can I add any offset f.e. when my mouse direction from the player is 2 units from the grappler point circle it will still grappler but automatically the grappler line will connect with the grappler point circle. Here is my grappler code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grappler: MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer Line;
    DistanceJoint2D Joint;
    Vector3 TargetPos;
    RaycastHit2D Hit;
    public float Distance = 10f;
    public LayerMask Mask;
    public float Step = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Joint = GetComponent<DistanceJoint2D>();
        Joint.enabled = false;
        Line.enabled = false;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(Joint.distance > 1f)
        {
            Joint.distance -= Step;
        }else
        {
            Line.enabled = false;
            Joint.enabled = false;
        }


        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            TargetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            TargetPos.z = 0;

            Hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, TargetPos - transform.position, Distance, Mask);

            if (Hit.collider != null && Hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
            {
                Joint.enabled = true;
                Joint.connectedBody = Hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                Joint.distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Hit.point);

                Line.enabled = true;
                Line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
                Line.SetPosition(1, Hit.point);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            Joint.enabled = false;
            Line.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: Is your question about UnityScript or C#?

Comment: My script is in c# and question too

Comment: I've removed the UnityScript tag then (since it's a separate programming language to C#).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should simply make your collision bigger by 2 units (if that's the amount you want to cheat by). And then instead of using the ray trace hit location, use the location of the object you hit instead.